# Find which of the abelian groups are isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_{6},\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3})$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Which of the abelian groups are isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_{6},\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3})$?

Comment: Is $\;Z_6\;$ the same as $\;\Bbb Z_6:=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\;$ ? And is $\;Q=\Bbb Q=$ the rationals? And what have you done so far?

Comment: Ok, a little help: under a group homomorphism, what can be the image in the rationals $\;\Bbb Q\;$ of an element of finite order?